# How to play MP3 audio with dynamic URL in HTML5 or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

In JavaScript or HTML5, how to play MP3 audio with *dynamic*, rather than *static*, URL?

Example - the following doesn't work:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%2C+World" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your example makes no example.

Comment: I have a feeling this could be because google prevents linking on allot off there resources from thrid party sites

Comment: @xiaoyi: My example demonstrates exactly what I need to do, but it seems that I used the wrong MIME type for the mp3 audio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's audio/mpeg, not audio/ogg, as seen from headers:

```
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
```

Try this:

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=Hello%2C+World" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCwHH/

Works in browsers that play mp3, like google chrome.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems I didn't pay attention to the MIME type.. 

I may also need to do this in HTML4. Do you know how? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in your example but as far as playing audio with HTML5 is concerned you can simply do it in these ways:

`Static Url:`

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="mySong.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

`Dynamic Url:` (just print that url in the src attribute)

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="<%Reponse.Write(url);%>" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Hope it solves this problem.